# Slide illusion creates flicker

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, autolayout, constraints

I'm creating a custom selected-animation for my `UITableView`.

What I've got is a standard `UIViewController` that displays a `UITableView`, which upon `didSelectRow:AtIndexPath:` instantiates another VC from storyboard, prepares it and displays it modally using `UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext`.

Then the second VC updates a constraint from the top layout guide to a `UIImageView`, hence placing it exactly where the cell was located on screen. This coordinate is passed from the first VC.

Next, this `UIImageView` slides up, creating the illusion that the cell slides up. However, this produces a flicker for a split second just before sliding the image quite often (not always, like 3/4 times).

**What's a better way to position the `UIImageView` initially, before it's animated?**

Here's my code doing this:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    self.imageViewTopConstraint.constant = self.cellFrame.origin.y;
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    self.imageView.image = self.image;
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:YES];
    /* animate the opening */
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.45 delay:0 usingSpringWithDamping:1.0f initialSpringVelocity:1.2f options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone animations:^{

        /* slide image */
        self.imageViewTopConstraint.constant = 0.0f;
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

    }completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
}
```

Comment: What kind of "flicker"? The image view position jumps around, or the whole screen blinks?

Comment: @AdamKaplan it's rather difficult to tell as it's very, very quick - but as far as I can tell it's from the image view position jumping around.

Comment: Try putting layoutIfNeeded just before the animation block. Also try manually calling setNeedsLayout before each layoutIfNeeded